# Install xgboost in Jupyter Notebook in AWS EC2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to install `xgboost` in `aws EC2` and use it in a `Jupyter` notebook. Until now I could install it using a simple `pip install xgboost`. When I run it in the terminal, there is not a problem. But when I try to run it on a `Jupyter` notebook, I get the error: `ImportError: No module named 'xgboost'`. Do you know why it happens?

I hope you can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this link has some answers. Apparently "If I launch jupyter notebook from Git Bash, then Xgboost does NOT work."
https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/1644

Comment: Could you flesh that out a little bit, maybe a more complete summary of the information in the github issue?